# How to stop regex from picking up character matches when Ctrl, Shift, etc. are pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom-events, keyevent

I was tasked with making a code that picks up when a key is pressed and counts the number of characters typed. I decided to use `var regex=/[a-zA-Z0-9]/;`, but to my surprise, when I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>, it would register all of them.

Here is the snippet of code that matters:

```js
window.onload = init;

function init() {
    window.onkeyup = incrementKey;
}

function incrementKey() {
    console.log(event.key)

    var regex=/[a-zA-Z0-9]/;

    if (event.key.match(regex)) {
        console.log(event.key)
    }
}
```

This way I’ll see the character show up twice if picked up by regex, and once if not.
And I have already tried nearly everything on the [W3Schools documentation on `RegExp`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

Things that I tried: `[A-Za-z0-9]`, `[^\n]` (also tried with `\0`, `\n`, `\f`, `\r`, `\t`, `\v`), `[\w]`, `[]` (obviously, at least, here, it doesn’t register any keys).

I was wondering how I can exclude the characters that don’t change the context of the text, other than manually typing every single character on its own.

Comment: Anchor the regex by the beginning and the end of the string: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/`

Comment: Pressing shift, `event.key` == "Shift" which (clearly) *does* match the regex of "contains any letter" - you could change your regex to `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/` so it only matches one character.

Comment: oh, its just I thought that you need to use those characters only when it has to be at the end/start of something, and `[a-zA-Z0-9]` without `+` would be just 1 character. Thanks!

Comment: The regular expression isn’t the issue. You need to use the [`KeyboardEvent` API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) to check if one of those keys have been pressed that don’t produce a character. Consider using the [`input` event](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) instead.

Comment: @SebastianSimon thanks for the suggestion! I got it working with `/^[a-zA-Z/W]$/`, but in the case of a text field where the `Enter` key would change the text, that would definitely come in handy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a regex to filter out the a-zA-Z0-9 characters then your original almost correct what your looking for is `^[a-zA-Z0-9]$` this regex will only match one character; anything between `^` and `$` in a regex means that the pattern must start at the beginning of a string and end at the end of a string. Your original answer failed because `[a-zA-Z0-9]` searches the string for all one character long alphanumerical substrings, obviously the string "Enter" still has alphanumerical characters therefore your regex.match will result in a match.

Alse you could consider using `regex.test(str)` as it returns a boolean, you can read more about it over at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test